# retrieving the data from firebase database and manipulate it in swift

Tags: database, swift, firebase

It's been a while that I have started working with firebase database.
here is my code :

```
let fbRef = Firebase(url: "https://mylogin-fb.firebaseio.com")
        var gatherData = fbRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {
            snapshit in
            print(snapshit.value)

            }, withCancelBlock: {

        error in
                print(error.description)

        })
```

and here is the results :

```
{
    "detail " = Swift;
    "title  " = programming;
}
```

How can I simply get the "Swift" or "programming" ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use objectForKey to retrieve data.

In your case :

```
let title = snapshot.value.objectForKey("title")
let detail = snapshot.value.objectForKey("detail")

print("Title : \(title), Detail : \(detail)")
```

Comment: but the answer is nil 
@Pipiks 

Title : nil, Detail : nil
Title : nil, Detail : nil
Title : nil, Detail : nil
Title : nil, Detail : nil
Title : nil, Detail : nil
Title : nil, Detail : nil

Comment: You tried with keys "title  " and "detail " as in your question ? (With spaces)